# SAT solvers that can compute prime implicants and/or minimization

Tags: sat-solvers, smt-solvers

I'm looking into computing the prime implicants of a Boolean function. I have found many different algorithms in the literature, many of them relying on SAT solvers. However, I have not been able to find a SAT solver that already provides this feature. Are there any?

Similarly, are there any SAT solvers/SMT solvers/related tools out there that work efficiently in practice for minimizing Boolean formulas?

Comment: Software recommendation is usually off-topic here.

Comment: http://www.sat4j.org/maven23/org.sat4j.core/apidocs/org/sat4j/minisat/core/Solver.html#primeImplicant()

Comment: Also, we normally prefer that you ask only one question per post.